LibreOffice Macros: how to apply paragraph style for every line starting with a number
I'm doing some postprocessing of javascript output in LibreOffice Writer.
I'd like to apply a separate paragraph style for every line that:

starts with a number (like 01.)
is a list and starts with the word "in".
is a list and starts with a different character

I have tried to do this in Search and Replace with the intent of recording it as a macro and editing it, but I have hit a wall, because:

The Search dialog allows to either search and replace text (also using RegEx), or search and replace paragraph styles, but not the combination thereof.
The macro recorded, while doing those two things separately, looks rather complicated, and I didn't really see any way how to correct it to do what I want.

Of course I tried a google search and here as well, but there was just nothing...
So I wrote this question, so that I may get some pointers on how to solve this situation.
Thanks a lot, have a nice day everyone!

Recording generates dispatcher code, which as you discovered, is difficult to work with. To learn how to write proper LibreOffice API code in Basic, a good place to start is https://www.pitonyak.org/oo.php. In particular for your task, check out 7.12. Setting Paragraph Style and 7.14. Search And Replace. If you try this and get stuck, edit the question and post the API code you have so far.

@JimK Thanks a lot, that looks much more logical. I will go through that and if there is a problem, I will ask again.
